# OBjective C: check the beginning of a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I must verify the beginning of a string: my example string is

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hello World";
```

then I must do an if, example:

```
 if (string1 startwith "Hello")
```

How can I do this in objective c?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
if ([string1 hasPrefix:@"Hello"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for the NSString class.  You'll find all kinds of surprises.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it this way:

```
NSRange aRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"Hello"];
if (aRange.location ==NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string not found");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string was at index %d ",aRange.location);
}
```

Based on the range, you can determine where in the string the item occurs

Comment: This works, but using `hasPrefix:` is easier and much more efficient. `hasPrefix:` can decide that it doesn’t match after looking at only one character while `rangeOfString:` has to scan the whole string.